# Making folders of images available in the project

Tags: java, android, image, file, android-studio

I need set of images in jpg format to be in this specific folder.

```
path = getFilesDir() + "/imagefiles/";
```

After root my mobile phone, I manage to find the specific folder. The location is */data/data/*packagename/files/imagesfile/*png* images. 
I can copy the image manually into the folder but i want to deploy a project that already has the image in it.

I have tried several solution but none really works for me. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> I can copy the image manually into the folder but i want to deploy a project that already has the image in it

It is not possible for you to create an app that automatically has files in `getFilesDir()` immediately upon installation.

What *is* possible is for you to put images there on the first run of your app. Those images could be:

- downloaded from the Internet
- packaged in `assets/` in the project, then copied into your desired location using `AssetManager` and `open()`
- packaged as raw resources in the project, then copied into your desired location using `Resources` and `openRawResource()`
- etc.

Comment: thanks, seems like you clarify my blur. will try the assets to copy to my directory.